# How to safely embed JSON with </script> in HTML document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, html-parsing

In a Rails 3.1 app, how can I safely embed some JSON data into an HTML document?

Suppose I have this in a controller action:

```
@tags = [
    {name:"tag1", color:"green"}, 
    {name:"</script><b>I can do something bad here</b>", color:"red"}
]
```

And this in a corresponding view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    var tags_list = <%= @tags.to_json %>;
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Then I get this in resulting HTML:

```
var tags_list = [
    {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;tag1&quot;,&quot;color&quot;:&quot;green&quot;},
    {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;b&gt;I can do something bad here&lt;/b&gt;&quot;,&quot;color&quot;:&quot;red&quot;}
];
```

which triggers a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` in Chrome

If I remove the Rails' default HTML escaping with `<%=raw tags.to_json
%>`, then it returns this:

```
var tags_list = [
    {"name":"tag1","color":"green"},
    {"name":"</script><b>I can do something bad here</b>","color":"red"}
];
```

which, of course, breaks the HTML document with `</script>`.

Can I somehow tell to_json() method to return something more like this:

```
var tags_list = [
    {"name":"tag1","color":"green"},
    {"name":"&lt;/script&gt;&lt;b&gt;I can do something bad here&lt;/b&gt;","color":"red"}
];
```

I asked this question on rubyonrails-talk mailing list, and I understand now that some people think that's a very bad idea to begin with, but in my case it works very nicely, as long as there are no HTML special chars in the data. So I just want to make the string returned by `to_json` HTML safe and still have JavaScript parse it properly.

**UPDATE:**
Based on @coreyward comment, I did make it a JS string literal, and that seems to be working great now. Its not quite as elegant of a solution as I was hoping for, but its not too bad either. Here is the code that is working for me:

```
<% tags = [{name:"tag1", color:"green"}, {name:"</script><b>I can \n\ndo something bad here</b>", color:"red"}] %>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    var tags_list = $.parseJSON('<%=j tags.to_json.html_safe %>');
    // ]]>
</script>
```

which results in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    var tags_list = $.parseJSON('[{\"name\":\"tag1\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"name\":\"<\/script><b>I can \\n\\ndo something bad here<\/b>\",\"color\":\"red\"}]');
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: HTML enclosed in a JS string literal shouldn't affect the rendering of the page. It should be treated like any other character in a string. You might want to investigate what is *really* happening when you use `raw tags.to_json`.

Comment: You **are** wrapping the JSON in `<script>` tags right?  As long as it's within a script, the HTML will be ignored... trust me you can have a JS string inside a script that has an entire page (`<html><head>`.. etc) of valid tags and it won't mess with rendering.

Comment: Second code snippet in my question is how I'm embedding it in HTML page. So it is inside `<script>` tags, and is not inside string literals, but rather like raw JS object.
This is working great as long as there are no HTML special chars in the `@tags` variable.

Comment: @coreyward you gave me an idea that I could just make it valid JS string and parse it with jQuery, which actually led me to a solution that I'm reasonably happy with. Thanks for that! :)
So instead of doing 
`var tags_list = <%= @tags.to_json %>;`
I'm now doing 
`var tags_list = $.parseJSON('<%=j tags.to_json.html_safe %>');`
and that gets the job done well enough for me.
Originally I wanted to have it in HTML as plain JS object/hash, but I'd rather have jQuery do the parsing, then me doing the proper HTML escaping of attributes on server for each object. This seems more generic to me.

Comment: Bounty message below should've been:  Is there really no standard way of escaping `"</script>"` strings inside JSON that's embedded directly into Rails views?

Comment: @nnc - do you have a link to your rubyonrails-talk discussion?  I'm interested to hear why they think it's a bad idea and what they suggest as alternatives when you want to pass JSON data to your javascript.

Comment: found the rubyonrails-talk discussion: https://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/4939f2d2f179157e/7dec5995ecb5735a

Comment: There's a better and safer way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176511/embedding-json-objects-in-script-tags

Answer (score 10):

Your code using just `@tags.to_json` works in rails3, *if* you enable it with:

```
   ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
```

Otherwise, your other option is this:

```
   var tags_list = <%= raw @tags.to_json.gsub("</", "<\\/") %>;
```

This saves the client having to parse the whole thing through $

Comment: actually activesupport escapes <, > and &. I think it would be best to do so yourselve as well if you want to be on the safe side.

Comment: Google gson (their java json encoder) makes a good case to replace the following characters with their unicode counterpart. < \u003c, > \u003e, & \u0026, = \u003d, ' \u0027 The reason for this is we as developers tend to stick json in a bunch of crazy places (eg attributes).

Answer (score 8):

The proper way in 2019 is to wrap `obj.to_json` with [`json_escape`](https://apidock.com/rails/ERB/Util/json_escape) function. `json_escape` is directly intended for escaping specific HTML symbols inside JSON strings. Example below from the documentation:

```rb
json = JSON.generate({ name: "</script><script>alert('PWNED!!!')</script>"})
# => "{\"name\":\"</script><script>alert('PWNED!!!')</script>\"}"

json_escape(json)
# => "{\"name\":\"\\u003C/script\\u003E\\u003Cscript\\u003Ealert('PWNED!!!')\\u003C/script\\u003E\"}"

JSON.parse(json) == JSON.parse(json_escape(json))
# => true
```

It seems this page appears on top of Google Search results, that's why I decided to provide a comment with an update :)

Comment: [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170217044954/https://apidock.com/rails/ERB/Util/json_escape) for json_escape

Answer (score 2):

btw, this works but is not a good solution in my opinion:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  //<![CDATA[
  var tags_list = <%=raw @tags.to_json.gsub('/', '\/') %>;
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: note: another relevant stack overflow discussion -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you try this it will work:

```
var tags_list = "<%== @tags.to_json.gsub('/', '\/') %>";
```

(Notice the double == and the " ")

Answer (score 0):

For instance with this in `app/layouts/application.html.slim`:

```
    javascript:
      window.translations = #{raw t("js").to_json};
```

And this in the translations:

```yaml
  js:
    name:
      must_be_present: Must be present<script>alert(1)</script>
```

The result will be escaped:

```html
<script>window.translations = {"name":{"must_be_present":"Must be present\u003cscript\u003ealert(1)\u003c/script\u003e"}};</script>
```