# Parse a hashtree containing HTML as JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, erb

I have been trying to figure out parsing a hashtree from rails backend as JSON in javascript. Have tried several solutions on stackoverflow and others including:

- http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/
- [Handling JSON in JS/ERB template in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757457/handling-json-in-js-erb-template-in-rails-3)
- [How to safely embed JSON with </script> in HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205902/how-to-safely-embed-json-with-script-in-html-document)

The object I am trying to parse:

```
{  
   "name"=>"map",
   "children"=>[  
      {  
         "name"=>"servicegroup1",
         "children"=>[  
            {  
               "name"=>"service1",
               "size"=>200,
               "id"=>10,
               "tooltip"=>"      <h3 id=\"status_tooltip_heading\">Service status<\/h3>\n      \n      <table id=\"status_tooltip_grid\">      \n        <tbody>\n          <tr>\n            <td>Status:<\/td>\n            <td>Unknown (an eternity ago)<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>\n          <tr>\n            <td>HTTP code:<\/td>\n            <td>\"N/A\"<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>                \n          <tr>\n            <td>Response time:<\/td>\n            <td>\"N/A\"<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>\n            <td>Event message:<\/td>\n            <td>Not pinged since eternity<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>\n        <\/tbody>\n      <\/table>\n"
            },
            {  
               "name"=>"service2",
               "size"=>200,
               "id"=>11,
               "tooltip"=>"      <h3 id=\"status_tooltip_heading\">Service status<\/h3>\n      \n      <table id=\"status_tooltip_grid\">      \n        <tbody>\n          <tr>\n            <td>Status:<\/td>\n            <td>Unknown (an eternity ago)<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>\n          <tr>\n            <td>HTTP code:<\/td>\n            <td>\"N/A\"<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>                \n          <tr>\n            <td>Response time:<\/td>\n            <td>\"N/A\"<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>\n            <td>Event message:<\/td>\n            <td>Not pinged since eternity<\/td>          \n          <\/tr>\n        <\/tbody>\n      <\/table>\n"
            },
            ...
         ]
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

Here is how I am currently trying to parse it as JSON in javascript, having tried the techniques in the above links.

```
<script>jsonObj = JSON.parse('<%==(raw @map.to_s).gsub("=>",":").gsub("</","<\\/") %>')</script>
```

Have been stuck on this for hours now. I would really appreciate any insight you could give me on this.
Also, the rails version is 4.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to use:

```
<script>jsonObj = <%=raw ( @map.to_json) %></script>
```

Comment: undefined method `gsub' for #<Hash:0x007f7d2000d558>
Tried j(@map.to_s) which is returning a string like: 
{\&quot;name\&quot;=&gt;\&quot;map\&quot;, \&quot;children\&quot;=&gt;[{\&quot;name\&quot;...

Comment: json_escape(@map) gives me a string like
{&quot;name&quot;=\u003e&quot;map&quot;, &quot;children&quot;=\u003e[{&quot;

Comment: Well, I didn't tested previous answer, but now it is fine. There's no need to use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: yeah I ended up doing the same and have been able to pin-point where exactly the problem is. I am updating it in my question.

Comment: Thanks a ton @blelump!
this method worked perfectly once I changed the quotes in my HTML content to single quotes and removed newlines!
I think you should add it to your answer for future reference.