# Newbie Node: referencing variables in javascript passed by res.render

Tags: node.js, pug

If I have a module that returns runs this:

```
res.render('index', {
    title:'Hello World'
});
```

I can access the title in jade by using #{title}.

How would I access it in separate .js javascript file included in the jade file?

Answer (score 2):

To access a jade variable in an external JavaScript file, the variable must be declared in a `script` tag *before* you link to the relevant JavaScript file.

For example, if you have a `script.js` file that needs to access the `title` variable in jade, you could use the following code in your jade file:

```
script.
    var jadeType = #{type}
script(type='text/javascript', src='./script.js')
```

The jade variable `type` can now be accessed in `script.js` using the JavaScript variable `jadeType`.

Hope this helps, if anyone is still looking for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jade, but assuming you mean another javascript file included on the rendered page, then you can probably do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var title = '#{title}';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** reference those thingie in external js files, included in your jade template.
Please, have a look here: [Accessing Express.js local variables in client side JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919650/accessing-express-js-local-variables-in-client-side-javascript)