# res.render() Locals Location on Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, express

This is probably a stupid question, but in Express, when you define local variables in `res.render(view, {variable: variable})`, how are they accessed on the frontend? Where are they kept? When I try to access a variable I defined through this method with `console.log(variable)` Firebug throws an error saying that `variable` is not defined. I also tried `console.log(window.variable)`, with similar results. So where are these variables kept?

Also, are `res.locals` variables kept in the same place, or are they just thrown out? These variables are accessible to templating engines like `swig` and `jade`, but I could not find them using `console.log()` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These variables are not passed automatically to client-side code; as you say, they're available to code in your view templates. Similarly, and variables defined in `res.locals` (or [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html%23app.locals), which has the same API) will be available as local variables in any views.

If you want to make them available to client side code, you'd have to manually send them as part of the response, in a form accessible to the client-side JavaScript. For instance, you could write them to a `<script>` tag, as is done here: [Accessing Express.js local variables in client side JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919650/accessing-express-js-local-variables-in-client-side-javascript) .

Comment: Darn, I was kind of hoping they put it directly in the global scope somehow, but now that I'm thinking about it, it makes sense that they need to be in a `<script>` tag first. Otherwise, how would code in later `<script>` tags know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

These variables are used for rendering the view on the server side only. Obviously some of these values make their way into the HTML of the server side response, but you probably want to look at a module such as [sharify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sharify) if you want to serialize these to JSON, embed into a `<script>` tag in the HTML, and get access to them in the browser javascript code.

Comment: I will probably just use JSON or JSONP. `sharify` looks interesting, but it probably puts the data directly inline in a `<script>` tag, as well, which I don't want.

Comment: Right, sharify is just for a "bootstrapping" case where you want to avoid the delay associated with an XmlHttpRequest for JSON.

Comment: Yes, that delay seems annoying. Unfortunately, it's starting to look like a choice between the delay and some worst practices like inline JavaScript.

Comment: IMHO this specific scenario bootstrapping data in a <script> tag results in a significant perceived performance increase, especially on high-latency connections, and thus it's a "best practice" IMHO for single-page apps to do some form of server side rendering and/or inlining data.

Comment: Yes but inline JavaScript is a very bad practice. It causes blending of presentation and business logic, makes it hard to test, among other things. These don't seem so bad with a tiny app, but it's a very slippery slope to the dark side.

Comment: XmlHttpRequest loads data into your app via a second HTTP request. Inlining stuffs it in the first response. It's a good compromise for now. HTTP2 may render it obsolete but what changes is the mechanism of loading data and that does NOT a priori constitute blending of presentation logic and business logic. It's not really "javascript" logic, it's just JSON data.

Comment: As I said, it's not too bad for tiny sites, but it's a slippery slope. You really need to keep all your logics and data all separate, and in HTML the standard for that is to keep all JavaScript in files separate from any HTML and reference it in `<script>` tags with the `src` attribute. It may not be the best, but it's better than spaghetti code.