# How to use EJS defined variables inside frontend JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have an Express app with a route like this:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  var choices = ["Batman", "Robin"];
  res.render("home", {choices: choices});
});
```

so that the `choices` variable is available to the view. In the view I have something like this, inside of a `script` tag:

```
var my_autoComplete = new autoComplete({
    selector: "#search",
    minChars: 1,
    source: function(term, suggest){
        var choices = ["Robin", "Batman"]; //I need it from the backend actually
        term = term.toLowerCase();
        var suggestions = [];
        for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
            if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term))suggestions.push(choices[i]);
              suggest(suggestions);
        }
});
```

(Basically it's a vanilla JavaScript input field that I've found on Internet).
For the script to work I have to define an array of choices, and in the script above I'm using a local `choices` variable. I want that `choices` variable the one coming from the backend.

How can I do that?
Would this be a poor designed page anyway?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133910/res-render-locals-location-on-frontend

Comment: @Jackyef, thank you.