# Why is 'message' undefined regarding connect-flash?

Tags: node.js, express, alert, connect-flash

I'm building an express app where when a user completes a form; if successful, they will see an alert confirming their submission.

In my server.js file, I am declaring

```
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
session = require("express-session"),
flash = require("connect-flash"),
app = express();
```

Followed by:

```
app.use(cookieParser("keyboard cat"));
app.use(session({ 
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
    secret: "keyboard cat" 
}));
app.use(flash());
require("./server/config/routes.js")(app);`
```

My routes file:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index", { message: req.flash("success") });
});

app.post("/sendMsg", function(req, res){
    mainController.sendMsg(req, res);
});

app.get("/sentSuccess", function(req, res){
    req.flash("success", "Thanks!");
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Finally in my main.js file for jquery calls (I'm using SweetAlert for alert styling):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(message){
    var frm = document.getElementsByName('msgForm')[0];
    swal({
        title: "Sweet!",
        text: "Thanks",
        imageUrl: "javascripts/sweetalert/thumbs-up.jpg"
    });
    frm.reset();
}
});
```

The issue I'm hitting is `Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined` on the client-side console. I've read through https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash and looked through the example at https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash/tree/master/examples/express3 but I'm not sure why message is not being passed back.

Comment: According to [this](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) it looks like `message` will be passed to the view. You might need to select the element first with JQuery before referencing it.

Comment: It looks like @trquoccuong has the right approach more or less. See [this](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919650/accessing-express-js-local-variables-in-client-side-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, the problem is with the way your code is trying to access the `message` variable. As @Pushkin said `message` will be passed to the view and can't be as such referenced by the javascript.

You can try this (in case you are using jade as view engine)

```
    if message
      .script
        // your javascript or function()
```

So finally code looks like :

```
if message
    .script
        var frm = document.getElementsByName('msgForm')[0];
            swal({
                title: "Sweet!",
                text: "Thanks",
                imageUrl: "javascripts/sweetalert/thumbs-up.jpg"
            });
            frm.reset();
```

Now you will be able to access the `message` variable.

In case if using `ejs` the syntax is almost similar

```
<% if (message) { %>
 // Do something here..
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was totally it. I am using ejs so I had to wrap a script tag & function in `<% if (message) { %> ...`. However, I ran into another issue where since my route for index was getting passed `message: req.flash("success")` it was automatically firing the script. My fix for that was to add in the following: `message: "undefined"`; then move the actual req.flash("success") parameter to my app.get("/sentSuccess") route and have that `res.render("index", {message: req.flash("success")});` and finally on my index view add in: `<% if(message != "undefined"){ %>`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a middleware :

```
app.use(flash());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.messages = req.flash();
  next();
});
```

Then use `messages` at frontend