# Accessing Express.js local variables in client side JavaScript (nunjucks)

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

This is bascially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919650/accessing-express-js-local-variables-in-client-side-javascript), except that I am using nunjucks as a template engine.

I am passing a variable to a nunjucks template using express's render method:

```
res.render('template.html', {myObject:myObject})
```

I want to access it in my client-side javascript.  So far, the only way I have figured out is to put it in an invisible HTML element and pull it into the javascript from there:

```
<span id='local-variable' style="display:none">{{ myObject.name }}</span>

<script>
    var myObjectName = $('#local-variable').text();
</script>
```

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [pipe](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#filters) of [`dump`](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/blob/f7153877c957762ee0c672c0fc5ab6b1db13a7d0/src/filters.js#L114) and [`safe`](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/blob/f7153877c957762ee0c672c0fc5ab6b1db13a7d0/src/filters.js#L125) filters:

```
<script>
    var myObjectName = {{ myObject.name | dump | safe }};
</script>
```