# How to understand =!{JSON.stringify(data)} syntax

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Can anyone help me what this small piece of code is doing in JavaScript?
Actually, I am getting data from express server in Json form and when I render my page I want to access that data in my client JavaScript and this solution I got from another question in Stack Overflow ([Accessing Express.js local variables in client side JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919650/accessing-express-js-local-variables-in-client-side-javascript)), but I am not able to understand this syntax.

```
var local_data =!{JSON.stringify(data)};
```

I am trying to interpret this but cant understand. I am using handlebars as my template engine.

Comment: Hello, are you sure there are curly braces on the right hand side {JSON.stringify(data)}

Comment: Exclamation mark simply inverts the result of the right hand side.
`var local_data = !false; //local_data will be true
var local_data = !true; //local_data will be false`

Comment: The code you've should is IMHO not executable. I've tried it multiple times. Could you check this please?

Comment: Not a valid expression at all

Comment: Where did this line come from and are you sure you aren't getting an error from it? The statement doesn't make a lot of sense. If you wanted to create an object, you would use `JSON.parse()`, not `JSON.stingify()` and there wouldn't be a need for the `{}`. Also, the `!` in front of the object would always return `false` as long as a valid object was created.

Comment: The `!` will invert the truth value of the expression. So if it is `true` it will become `false` and vice versa. The only use I can imagine is if you try to `JSON.parse(undefined)` your result will be `undefined` and if you invert it, it will become `true`. It could be used to do some edge case testing if someone provides an undefined object. But there are better ways to do that...so the reason for all of this remains mysterious to me.

Comment: actually i m getting data from express server in json form and i want to get that data in my client side javascript for which i tried to search on stack overflow but i got this type of expression for parse data in client javascript . but i am not being able to undertstand this. i m using handlebars as my template engine

Comment: this must be !JSON.stringify(data)... It interprets to if stringified `data` object exists or not. 
From strigified, we means `data` must be object and we typecast it to string.

Comment: @HaroonAli Can you edit that information into your question?

Comment: `i want to get that data in my client side javascript` ...that's a fairly simple and common requirement. `Json.parse()` should be sufficient for doing that. It will turn a JSON string into a usable JavaScript variable. I don't know what youv'e been searching for but the code above is really strange, to say the least.

Comment: If you simply want to process the JSON data you are receiving, all you need to do is: `let obj = JSON.parse(data);`. After that, you will have a JavaScript object and can do whatever you want with it. The code you've shown is nonsensical.

Comment: There are plenty of clues on that page that what you copied is not JavaSCript, like the fact that people are talking about "Jade templates", the answer begins "Using Jade templating..." the instructions are to put this code it in your `views/index.jade`, and the full context of the code is `!!! 5` `script(type='text/javascript')` `var local_data =!{JSON.stringify(data)}`, the first two lines of which are not JavaScript either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question where you took that from code indicates that the code is part of a [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) template. I searched around for this exact line of code and found it referenced [here](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/2897907) and [here](https://recalll.co/ask/v/topic/node.js-Accessing-Express.js-local-variables-in-client-side-JavaScript/554cd50204ce0263778b7750), both of which also reference Jade.

In other words, this *isn't* valid JavaScript, but it *is* valid Jade. In this case, `!{...}` are Jade's syntax for [unescaped string interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation).

The equivalent in [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) is `{{{...}}}`, so try this:

```
var local_data = {{{JSON.stringify(data)}}};
```