# How do I escape closing '/' in HTML tags in JSON with Python?

Tags: python, html, django, escaping

Note: This question is very close to [Embedding JSON objects in script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176511/embedding-json-objects-in-script-tags), but the responses to that question provides what I already know (that in JSON `/` == `\/`).  I want to know how to do that escaping.

The HTML spec prohibits closed HTML tags anywhere within a `<script>` element. So, this causes parse errors:

```
<script>
var assets = [{
  "asset_created": null, 
  "asset_id": "575155948f7d4c4ebccb02d4e8f84d2f", 
  "body": "<script></script>"
}];
</script>
```

In my case, I'm generating the invalid situation by rendering a JSON string inside a Django template, i.e.:

```
<script>
var assets = {{ json_string }};
</script>
```

I know that JSON parses `\/` the same as `/`, so if I can just escape my closing HTML tags in the JSON string, I'll be good.  But, I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

My naive approach would just be this:

```
json_string = '[{"asset_created": null, "asset_id": "575155948f7d4c4ebccb02d4e8f84d2f", "body": "<script></script>"}]'
escaped_json_string = json_string.replace('</', r'<\/')
```

Is there a better way? Or any gotchas that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Okay I assumed a few things incorrectly. For escaping the JSON, the [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) library has a method [JSONEncoderForHTML](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#simplejson.JSONEncoderForHTML) than can be used. You may need to install it via `pip` or `easy_install` if the code doesn't work. Then you can do something like this:

```
import simplejson
asset_json=simplejson.loads(json_string)
encoded=simplejson.encoder.JSONEncoderForHTML().encode(assets_json)
```

which `encoded` will give you this:

```
'{"asset_id": "575155948f7d4c4ebccb02d4e8f84d2f", "body": "\\u003cscript\\u003e\\u003c/script\\u003e", "asset_created": null}'
```

This is a more overall solution than the slash replace as it handles other encoding caveats as well.

The `loads` part is a side-effect of having the JSON already encoded. This can be avoided by not using DJango if possible to generate the JSON and instead using simplejson:

```
simplejson.dumps(your_object_to_encode, cls=simplejson.encoder.JSONEncoderForHTML)
```

**Old Answer**

Try wrapping your script in [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var assets = [{
  "asset_created": null, 
  "asset_id": "575155948f7d4c4ebccb02d4e8f84d2f", 
  "body": "<script></script>"
}];
//]]>
</script>
```

It's meant to flag the parser on this sort of thing. Otherwise you'll need to use the character escapes that have been mentioned.

Comment: But this only works for XHTML, right?  With ``<!doctype html>``, ``CDATA`` doesn't seem to work.  That's why I preferred the ``\/`` escaping in the JSON.  The question was more about how to do the string replacement for the escaping than how to escape the text itself.

Comment: @GeoffreyHing Ah yes I incorrectly assumed the XHTML part. I've updated my answer for the DJango escaping part.

Comment: @GeoffreyHing: django ships with its own copy of simplejson which you can import using `from django.utils import simplejson` so you would not need to install it separately.

Comment: @LieRyan, unfortunately, it looks like the version of simplejson that comes with Django (at least 1.4) doesn't included the ``JSONEncoderForHTML`` encoder.