# Removing \ characters from HTML template

Tags: json, python-3.x, lambda

I have a lambda function where I render an HTML template and pass it back to API Gateway for it to be rendered when somebody hits our endpoint. What I am finding is that when I return the HTML, all these escape characters are being added.

Below is the full function:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    html_data =''
    with app.app_context():
        html_data = render_template('index.html')
    
    return {
        "body":html_data
    }
```

So do not get lost in all the code, but what is happening is that all these \n and \ characters are appearing all over the HTML file.

Below is the Response:

```
Response
{
    "body": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\">\n  <head>\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css\" integrity=\"sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n    <script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\n    <script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\n    <script src=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <title></title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <ul class='nav'>\n      <li class='nav-link'>\n        <a href=\"#\">Home</a>\n      </li>\n      <li class='nav-link'>\n        <a href=\"#\">About</a>\n      </li>\n      <li class='nav-link'>\n        <a href=\"#\">Log Out</a>\n      </li>\n      <li class='nav-link'>\n        <a href=\"#\">Account</a>\n      </li>\n      <li class='nav-link'>\n        <a href=\"#\">Create Post</a>\n      </li>\n      <li class='nav-link'>\n        <a href=\"#\">Log In</a>\n      </li>\n      <li class='nav-link'>\n        <a href=\"#\">Register</a>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n<div class=\"container\">\n  \n  <div class=\"jumbotron\">\n    <h1>Puppy Company Blog</h1>\n  </div>\n\n</div>\n  </body>\n</html>"
}
```

I am not sure what is causing this, but I am surely doing something wrong here.

EDIT UPDATE:

I found the following SOF post, which I think might get me on the right track.

[How do I escape closing '/' in HTML tags in JSON with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297028/how-do-i-escape-closing-in-html-tags-in-json-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method Response

- Navigate to the Method Response for the API's GET method.
- Open up the 200 under HTTP Status and add a Response Header named Content-Type. Be sure to save it with the green check mark. If you try pressing enter to save it will clear the field and not save.
- Delete the application/json Response Model for 200.

[image]

**

### Integration Response

**

- Navigate to the Integration Response for the API's GET method.
- Open up the 200 Response, Header Mappings, and Mapping Templates.
  Edit the Response Header Content-Type and set the Mapping value to 'text/html' (be sure
  to use single quotes). Don't forget to save it with the green checkmark icon.
- Delete the application/json Content-Type under Mapping Templates.
- Add the Content-Type text/html (no quotes this time).
- Select Mapping Template in the right-hand drop-down box.
- Set the value of Template to $input.path('$') and save with the green checkmark.

**Deploy & test the API**