# How to inject data from db into jade template?

Tags: mongodb, express, pug

I am trying to import data from mongodb into **jade** template, in order to show them in graph. I am using **chart.js** inline script, in order to render data on graph. So data from Mongodb is on the page, and I can access it like this:

```
each city in cities
    p #{city.name}
```

And here is how I pass data to page:

```
exports.index = function(req,res){
    var cities = City.find({}).limit(20);
    cities.exec(function(err,doc) {
        res.render("index",{cities:doc});
    });
};
```

I created same app with **php**, by simply passing data to page and injecting data into javascript graph(**with json_encode**)

[Here is final result with php:](http://l4blog.eu1.frbit.net/chart)

It was easy, since **php** data are global to HTML page. How to do that with **Jade** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, so your goal is to both use the city data to generate HTML on the server but ALSO make it available in the browser as raw javascript object data. To do that you format it as JSON and stuff it into a `<script>` tag. There are modules to help with this such as [sharify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sharify),
but the basic idea in your jade template do something like:

In your express route handler javascript:

```
exports.index = function(req,res){
    var cities = City.find({}).limit(20);
    cities.exec(function(err,doc) {
        //There are tricky rules about safely embedding JSON within HTML
        //see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4180424/266795
        var encodedCityData = 'window.cities = ' + JSON.stringify(cities)
            .replace(/</g, '\\u003c')
            .replace(/-->/g, '--\\>');
        res.render("index",{cities:doc, encodedCityData: encodedCityData});
    });
};
```

In your jade template:

```
script!= encodedCityData
```

In the browser, you will have access to the data via the `cities` variable which has been set onto the `window` object.

Comment: thanks for answer - I did pass data - see my updated question.

Comment: great - I had same problem with json and php.In the mean time I found that fetching data with ajax is much easier, because I am working with js data.