# How to use object passed to index.jade in browserified script?

Tags: node.js, browserify, pug-loader

I am trying out browserify and ran into a problem with my project structure.
I send an array to index.jade via routing from index.js. That seems to work and in the index.jade the length of the array is displayed:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title 
  p= spectra.length
  div#cy
  script(src="javascripts/code.js")
```

Code.js is a number of classes (ES6 which is babelified) packaged by browserify.
That seems to work until I try to use spectra:

```
"use strict";
const GraphSpectrum = require("./GraphSpectrum");
let gms = new GraphSpectrum(spectra[0]); 
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({ //...
```

ReferenceError: spectra is not defined

browserify creates code.js and at the end of the generated code it includes my client code:

```
......
},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

console.log(spectra.length);
console.log(spectra);

const GraphSpectrum = require("./GraphSpectrum");
const MSSpectrum = require("./MSSpectrum");

let mgfSection = ["BEGIN IONS", "PEPMASS=491.222686767578", "CHARGE=2", "TITLE=491.222686767578_1494.17_scan=6268_2014090922Mix2alkylISW10noEclu,seq={ATNYNAGDR},sup={4}", "SCANS=0", "491.2227\u00092", "128.1677\t34.3", "143.9659    14.8", "145.1864    1063.5", "147.2310  164.8", "148.0274   88.9", "152.2586    32.3", "153.1165    141.1", "155.0703   453.6", "156.2521   121.2", "158.0017   158.1", "162.1551   94.7", "163.1792    69.3"];
let msms = new MSSpectrum();
msms.parseMGFSection(mgfSection);
let gms = new GraphSpectrum(msms);
console.log(gms.nodes);
console.log(gms.getEdges('sequence'));
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,
  style: [{
    selector: 'node',
    css: {
      'content': 'data(id)',
      'text-valign': 'center',
      'text-halign': 'center'
    }
  }, {
    selector: '$node > node',
    css: {
      'padding-top': '1px',
      'padding-left': '1px',
      'padding-bottom': '1px',
      'padding-right': '1px',
      'text-valign': 'top',
      'text-halign': 'center',
      'background-color': '#bbb'
    }
  }, {
    selector: 'edge',
    css: {
      'curve-style': 'bezier',
      'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
    }
  }, {
    selector: ':selected',
    css: {
      'background-color': 'black',
      'line-color': 'black',
      'target-arrow-color': 'black',
      'source-arrow-color': 'black'
    }
  }],
  elements: {
    nodes: gms.nodes,
    edges: gms.getEdges('sequence') 
  },
  layout: {
    name: 'preset',
    padding: 5
  }
}); 

},{"./GraphSpectrum":1,"./MSSpectrum":3}]},{},[4]);
```

The code works and the results are displayed when I remove spectra reference.
How do I access the global variable available in pug within this code section?

What am I missing?

Thank you,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

What I was overlooking is that variables available to Jade/Pug are not available for client scripts in the browser. These have to be passed on first. 
The way how to do that is described here: [Variables, global objects, and console.log in jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726567/variables-global-objects-and-console-log-in-jade)

In my case I added:

```
script(type="text/javascript")!= "var clientSpectra = " + JSON.stringify(spectra)
```

to the index.jade